# Android LVL Developer Test not working

Tags: android, testing, android-lvl

I always get "ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED" respone from google... And the first time I always get a "RETRY" response

I've made sure:

- that I'm using the correct public key
- that I have only my google developer account on my test phone
- that I've set the license test answer to licensed in the developer console

As far as I know, I DON'T have to upload my app to test it with the developer account (that is written below the license test answer drop down field)

What else do I have to do?

Comment: no, and that's not necessary... btw, it already works, but thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as *I* recall, you *do* have to upload a draft of your app for testing with the developer account, but not for testing with the admin account. But anyway, upload it and you'll be fine.

Comment: there is the developer and test accounts... the first one does not need to upload apk... that's how it's stated on the side... anyway, I tried uploading it already and that did not solve the problem either... (I even used the exactly same apk to test after the upload)...

Comment: @prom85 Is the package name correct? When did you upload it; there are some delays with Google Play?

Comment: what do you mean with correct package name? but I will wait now some time, maybe it works if I wait longer... didn't wait too long yet, because I was sure (because it's stated in the developer console), that the developer does not have to upload an apk...

Comment: @prom85 The LVL service call is specified as follows: `oneway interface ILicensingService { void checkLicense(long nonce, String packageName, in ILicenseResultListener listener); }` It needs the right package name. The Google "example" code will retrieve it from the context I think, so it must be identical on Google Play.
}

Comment: ok, I see what you mean... yeah, that name is correct as well, I'm retrieving it via `getPackageName()` and checked it as well....

Comment: ok, waiting was the solution... now it works... I will try if it works without uploading... but now it at least works after it was uploaded...